# How to output different values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, variables, arraylist

I have a problem with my code. what I want to do is to delete an item from the array when it has been called meaning that, I want every output to be different. I want to use it to rotate proxy and there are over 150 proxies in the array. Here's an example of my code.

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < 2; $i++ )
{
  // If the array_history is empty, re-populate it.
  if (empty($array_history))
    $array_history = $array;

  // Select a random key.
  $key = array_rand($array_history, 1);

  // Save the record in $selected.
  $selected = $array_history[$key];

  // Remove the key/pair from the array.
  unset($array_history[$key]);

  // Echo the selected value.
  echo $selected; 
}
```

How can I do this or is a for loop not suitable for this? thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Please give some example data and what you want as output. Take a look at [ask] and [edit] your question.

Comment: I've edited my question and explained more, can you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good application for a [generator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php). This one takes an array of proxy addresses and loops over the array in random order, shuffling the array each time it starts the loop again.

```
function get_proxy($proxies) {
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($proxies);
    while (true) {
        if ($i == 0) shuffle($proxies);
        yield $proxies[$i];
        $i = ($i + 1) % $len;
    }
}
```

To use this, you would do something like this:

```
$proxies = array('10.0.0.4', '192.168.0.1', '10.1.0.1');
$i = 0;
foreach (get_proxy($proxies) as $proxy) {
    echo "$proxy\n";
    $i++;
    // stop otherwise infinite loop
    if ($i == 9) break;
}
```

Note that since the generator has an infinite loop in it, the external `foreach` loop will also be infinite, and so needs a way to break out (I've used a simple counter in this case).

Sample output for the above code:

```
10.1.0.1
10.0.0.4
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1
10.1.0.1
10.0.0.4
10.1.0.1
192.168.0.1
10.0.0.4
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/q3UT7)

If a generator doesn't suit your code structure, you could use a function with static variables to return a new proxy on each call:

```
$proxies = array('10.0.0.4', '192.168.0.1', '10.1.0.1');

function get_proxy($proxies) {
    static $i = 0, $keys;
    if (!isset($keys)) $keys = array_keys($proxies);
    if ($i == 0) shuffle($keys);
    $proxy = $proxies[$keys[$i]];
    $i = ($i + 1) % count($keys);
    return $proxy;
}

for ($i= 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    echo get_proxy($proxies) . "\n";
}
```

Sample output for this code:

```
10.1.0.1
10.0.0.4
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1
10.1.0.1
10.0.0.4
10.0.0.4
192.168.0.1
10.1.0.1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UDHjd)

Comment: @Xternet not sure if you saw the original answer, but if that doesn't suit I've updated with a different function that can give the same results in a more flexible manner (it can be called as a function, unlike the generator).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used the function with static variables.

Comment: @Xternet I'm glad one of them worked for you. It was an interesting problem.

Comment: I'm getting this error in CLI, although the parameters are correct    ```Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /storage/emulated/0/hyperlook/hyperlooko.php on line 219

Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /storage/emulated/0/hyperlook/hyperlooko.php on line 220

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /storage/emulated/0/hyperlook/hyperlooko.php on line 222
```

Comment: do I need to put the proxies array inside the function ?

Comment: @Xternet you just need to pass it as a parameter as I have shown in the sample code and demo.

Comment: @Xternet according to the error message you give, you have passed a `null` value to the function (or no value at all)

Comment: I didn't change anything in the code. I renamed my proxy list array to $proxies but it's still not working ```function get_proxy($proxies) {
    static $i = 0, $keys;
    if (!isset($keys)) $keys = array_keys($proxies);
    if ($i == 0) shuffle($keys);
    $proxy = $proxies[$keys[$i]];
    $i = ($i + 1) % count($keys);
    return $proxy;
}```

Comment: What does the call to `get_proxy` look like?

Comment: ```if ($proxy == '2') {
$proxy = get_proxy($proxies);
        }
        

    try {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.instagram.com', 
                                [
                                    "timeout" => 60,
                                    "proxy" => $proxy
                                ]);......... ```

Comment: That should work unless the value of `$proxies` is `null` or `$proxies` is unset when you make the call

Comment: It only works if I put it this way``` 
function get_proxy($proxies) {$proxies = array('10.0.0.4', '192.168.0.1', '10.1.0.1');

    static $i = 0, $keys;
    if (!isset($keys)) $keys = array_keys($proxies);
    if ($i == 0) shuffle($keys);
    $proxy = $proxies[$keys[$i]];
    $i = ($i + 1) % count($keys);
    return $proxy;
}```

Comment: @Xternet that is weird. But if you are putting the proxies into the function, this is simpler: https://3v4l.org/Jbb7R

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I upvoted your answer but it's not showing

Comment: @Xternet you don't have enough rep to upvote yet. When you do it will show up.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is spread access over 150 proxies. In this case, it is not really necessary to do it randomly. You can just go through the array.

```
<?php 

$array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

for ( $i = 1; $i < 20; $i++ )
{
    echo getNext($array) . '<br>';
}

function getNext (&$array) {
  $e = next($array); // Every time next element is selected. Each output is different.
  if ($e)
    return $e;
  else 
    return reset($array);
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to achieve is to get only one output but it should be different everytime

Comment: By calling getNext($array) you get one result, different every time.

Comment: I upvoted you but I don't know why it's not showing

Answer (score 0):

When you define an array in php such as

```
<?php
$alphabet = array(a, b, c)
?>
```

Your trying to look for the elements in the array. The element list always starts at a count of 0. So to call individual elements count from left to right starting at 0.

```
<?php
#a
echo $alphabet[0];

#b
echo $alphabet[1];

#c
echo $alphabet[2]; 

?>
```

The above section should yield a result of abc because there are no breaks.

For loops are really handy for going through the entire array and running checks, error analysis or even math as examples.

Comment: I know about this already. In the original code I have more that 150 elements in the array. As you can see in the code, what I want to do is to delete an item from the list when it has been called, I want every output to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed tho cede slightly, to me it reads as code that will take a selection of items, pick one at random, discard the item, and then pick again until none are left.  If there are none left, copy the original array and start again.

Currently your code loops once.  I've extended the loop to 4 iteratons here.  And upon each random selection, am storing that random key in a history array.  You can then refer to that history later in your code.

```
<?php
$array = 
[
    'beatle' => 'John',
    'stone' => 'Mick',
    'floyd' => 'Syd'
];

for ($history = [], $i = 1; $i < 5; $i++)
{
  if (empty($buffer))
    $buffer = $array;

  $key = array_rand($buffer, 1);
  $history[] = $key;

  echo $buffer[$key], "\n";

  unset($buffer[$key]);
}

var_export($history);
```

Example output:

```
Syd
Mick
John
Syd
array (
  0 => 'floyd',
  1 => 'stone',
  2 => 'beatle',
  3 => 'floyd',
)
```

Referring to the history array above:

```
echo $array[$history[3]];
```

Would output `Syd`.

Adapting and encapsulating the above in a class. This will do the same (but not store the history of picks), taking an item from an array at random and remove until there are no more items in the array, and then replenish the list and so on:

```
class RandomProxies
{
    const PROXIES = 
    [
        'proxy1' => 'foo.example.com',
        'proxy2' => 'bar.example.com',
        'proxy3' => 'baz.example.com',
    ];

    private $buffer;

    public function getProxy() {
        if (empty($this->buffer))
            $this->buffer = self::PROXIES;
        $key = array_rand($this->buffer);
        $proxy = self::PROXIES[$key];
        unset($this->buffer[$key]);

        return $proxy;
    }
}

$randomiser = new RandomProxies;

foreach(range(1,4) as $n) {
    echo $randomiser->getProxy(), "\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
foo.example.com
baz.example.com
bar.example.com
foo.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to use the code to rotate proxy and what I want it to do is to take selection of proxies in the array, pick only one at random, discard the list, and then pick again until there's no more proxy in the list. If there are none left, copy the original array and start all over again. The problem is, I get repeated output.

Comment: @Xternet that's pretty much what the code does.  I'm not sure what problem you are having?  I've encapsulated my adapted code above.  Perhaps that's more what you are after.  Note you will potentially get a duplicate upon list replenishes.